# I have a string in a <td> that needs to be styled in parts

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have the string "Total (incl.tax) $2.81"

in a table's cell:

```
<table>
    <body>
        <tr>
            <td>Total (incl.tax) $2.81</td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</table>
```

I need to style it so that the "(incl.tax)" part is 2px smaller than the rest of the line. I've search StackOverflow and other sites, and have not found an answer to my question:

How would I go about doing this with css?

I don't want to change the text in any other way, otherwise I could have used something similar to this:

```
<td style="font-size: 15px">Total <em style="font-size: 13px">(incl.tax)</em> $2.81</td>
```

Comment: Wrap the text in a span and have style on that. e.g. `td > span {...}`.

Comment: "2px smaller than the rest of the line" is context-sensitive to your situation. If the font size for your table cell was, say 14px, then you could specify 12px for (incl.tax) *or* you could use relative units and specify 0.857em or 85.7% for (incl.tax). That way if you need to adjust the font size of your table, the smaller text will scale proportionally. See [pxtoem.com](http://pxtoem.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use span for that

```
<td>Total <span style="font-size:10px;">(incl.tax)</span> $2.81</td>
```

like wise

Answer (score 3):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Total <small>(incl.tax)</small> $2.81</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can then target the `<small/>` element to refine:

```
td small { font-size: 80%; }
```

Also note that I've corrected an error in your code: `<body>` should be `<tbody>`

Comment: Thanks, I was in a hurry and left it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<td>Total <span style="font-size:9px;">(incl.tax)<span> $2.81</td>
```

Give the font size according to your code. so that it become the 2px smaller.

Answer (score 1):

add span tag before (incl.tax) and give css span tag

Answer (score 0):

Use following style:

```
<style>
    .largefontdemo {
          font-size: 20px;
    }
    .smallfontdemo{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<table class="largefontdemo">
    <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Total <span class="smallfontdemo">(incl.tax)</span> $2.81</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

one more thing instead of `body` in your html for table, you have to write tbody

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this without changing the content somehow, since in CSS, you can only style elements and pseudo-elements, and the parenthetic expression as such does not constitute an element or a pseudo-element.

You could however change the content client-side, with simple JavaScript (or jQuery) code that processes the relevant elements, recognizes the parenthetic expressions, and wraps suitable markup (most logically and robustly: `<small>` and `</small>`) around them. The details would depend on the exact format of the content and the structure of the document and which cells need to be considered.

(Using `em` would not be optimal on three grounds: it logically means emphasis, and this text should be “de-emphasized” rather than emphasized; it changes the default rendering to italic; it does not change the font size in default rendering, unlike `small` does.)

Answer (score -3):

try this

HTML

```
<table>
    <body>
        <tr>
            <td>Total <span>(incl.tax)</span> $2.81</td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td > span{
    font-size:2px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you specify a class if you don't use it?

Comment: by my mistake sorry i upload old.